# How do I get the continuation mapping from the URL in a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapping

I have this spring application where I want to get the values from a URL, for example:

The url send to the spring application is `www.example.com/app/account/register`. How do I get the `/register` part after `/account` when my code looks like this.

For this example I used `/register` but this can be `/login`, `/something` as well.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account")
    public boolean AccountServer(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @RequestBody Map<String, String> payLoad){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can have other controller methods that handle `/account/register`, `/account/login`, `/account/someting` etc..

Comment: Yes, but this is something I want to avoid because this is going to be a micro service and the /register part needs to be send to another service. A bit like a gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@PathVariable` annotation to get the value.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/{operation}")
    public boolean AccountServer(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
                                 @RequestBody Map<String, String> payLoad,
                                 @PathVariable("operation") String operation){
  
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UriComponentsBuilder as a parameter, it will be injected by Spring and initialized with current URI. You can then convert to UriComponents [UriComponents](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html) to query the path.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/account")
    public boolean AccountServer(UriComponentsBuilder builder, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @RequestBody Map<String, String> payLoad){
        List<String> pathSegments = builder.build().getPathSegments();
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```